# Is it possible to access the content of a sharepoint 2010 wiki article externally via php?

Tags: wiki, wiki-pages

Title basically says all. I have external web pages that I would like to access the content of certain wiki articles using php, or other methods if anyone has suggestions.

Is this possible? If not can anyone think of any work arounds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to access content in SharePoint 2010, the main problem you have to face would be authentication. Assuming that is out of the way you have essentially:

1. SOAP Web Services (located all under _vti_bin) - see here http://davidsit.wordpress.com/2010/03/03/creating-sharepoint-list-items-with-php/
2. ListData.svc  - REST based API allows for content only access. Get started at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798339.aspx and here http://www.dotnetmafia.com/blogs/dotnettipoftheday/archive/2010/01/21/introduction-to-querying-lists-with-rest-and-listdata-svc-in-sharepoint-2010.aspx.

You would need to look for the WikiField as being the field storing the actual HTML content of a basic Wiki Page. Also, make sure you are not hitting Publishing sites - that would complicate things for you!